# Posicionamento de li's na página

Tags: html, css

gostaria de fazer com que meus li se espalham de forma uniforme pela largura da página.

Como posso fazer isso com css?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade [display: table](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), exemplo:

```css
ul.menu{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  display: table;
 }
 ul.menu li {
   background-color:gray;
   display: table-cell;
 }
ul.menu li a{
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). A maioria dos *browsers* tem uma implementação já bem consolidada, de acordo com o [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Estou assumindo que a sua lista será horizontal, ou seja, os `<li>`s estarão um ao lado do outro. O segredo está em declarar o seu `<ul>`, que é o seu *container* como `display: flex`, e nas `<li>`s setar a propriedade `flex-grow: 1`.  Esta propriedade define a possibilidade de um item *flex* crescer, se necessário. Definindo-a como 1, todo o espaço restante do *container* será distribuido igualmente entre seus filhos.

Veja:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('ul').append('<li>Teste</li>');
});
```

```css
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

li{
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

button{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Adicionar LIs</button>

<ul>
  <li>Teste</li>
  <li>Teste</li>
</ul>
```

Obviamente, esse código deve ser adequado às suas necessidades.

Answer (score 2):

Se você souber o número exato de `<li>`'s então use o código abaixo, ajustando a porcentagem para coincidir os 100%:

```
<style>
    li {            
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nesse caso não precisaria do float. Na verdade ou usa o float ou usa o inline-block. Acontece que o inline-block tem um problema conhecido de uma margem de 4px. Aqui tem mais informações: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
 margin:0; 
}
ul {
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 0;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>OLÁ</li>
  <li>HELLO</li>
  <li>HOLA</li>
</ul>
```

EXPLICAÇÂO:

1. Definimos o elemento pai (neste caso o ul) como tendo o comprimento da página (width: 100%)
2. `font-size:0;`: isto serve para que não haja margens nos elementos filhos que tenham como display `inline-block`, o nosso `<li>`
3. dividimos 100 (100%) por o numero total de `<li>`, isto vai dar-nos os comprimento de cada um relativamente ao elemento pai... Que tem o comprimento da janela

Comment: Legal, mais e se a quantidade de elementos for dinâmica?

Comment: Divide 100% pela quantidade de elementos, isto com javascript @abfurlan